# Using btoa to parse xls from javascript to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, excel

I have written a program that sends an excel file uploaded by the user from javascript to `C#` where it is then formatted. The code works well for `.xlsx` files; however, when I try to parse `.xls` files, I receive the following error:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name:
>   s'.

After some further testing with breakpoints, I believe I have found the problem, but I cannot find a solution. The following code is the javascipt used to encode the file:

```
document.getElementById('selectedFile').addEventListener('change', function (event) {

var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function () {
    filename = event.target.files[0].name;
    var uint8Array = new Uint8Array(this.result);
    fileContent = btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uint8Array));

}
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);

}, false);
```

When the file uploaded is of type `.xlsx`, `fileContent` returns the correct value; however, if an `.xls` file is uploaded, it returns `null`, therefore breaking the code further on.

Is there a way to make this code work for `.xls` files? Alternatively, is there a way I can convert it to `.xlsx` before I parse it to the backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.xlsx` is a text format (XML) so `String.fromCharCode` should work appropriately.

`.xls` is a binary file format.  I would **not** expect String functions to work properly with it.

You can use Excel to convert between formats.  The conversion is non-trivial and, while not impossible to do from javascript, probably not worth spending a couple months on.